# ServletRequest.getParameterMap() returns Map<String, String[]> and ServletRequest.getParameter() returns String?

Tags: java, servlets

Can someone explain to me why `ServletRequest.getParameterMap()` returns type

```
Map<String, String[]>
```

`ServletRequest.getParameter()` just returns type `String`

I'm don't understand why the map would ever map to more then one value. TIA.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

It returns all parameter values for controls with the **same** name.

For example:

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="cars" value="audi" /> Audi
<input type="checkbox" name="cars" value="ford" /> Ford
<input type="checkbox" name="cars" value="opel" /> Opel
```

or

```html
<select name="cars" multiple>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    <option value="ford">Ford</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
</select>
```

Any checked/selected values will come in as:

```
String[] cars = request.getParameterValues("cars");
```

It's also useful for multiple selections in tables:

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Delete?</th>
        <th>Foo</th>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach items="${list}" var="item">
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="${item.id}"></td>
            <td>${item.foo}</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

in combination with

```
itemDAO.delete(request.getParameterValues("delete"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It make perfect sense now. Sometimes it's easy to miss the obvious stuff. I guess that's what this web site if for :).

Answer (score 22):

```
http://foo.com/bar?biff=banana&biff=pear&biff=grape
```

"biff" now maps to `{"banana","pear","grape"}`

Answer (score 11):

The real function to get all parameter values is

```
   request.getParameterValues();
```

`getParameter()` is just a shortcut to get first one.

Answer (score 3):

In the case with multi-value controls (checkbox, multi-select, etc), the `request.getParameterValues(..)` is used to fetch the values.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a multi-value control like a multi-selectable list or a set of buttons mapped to the same name multiple selections will map to an array.

Comment: I am not sure if I see the value in case of buttons. In decent browsers it will only return the value of the **pressed** button, not the value of **all** buttons.