# Passing multiple request parameters with same name from table rows

Tags: jsp, servlets, http-request-parameters, multiple-value

I have a table with checkboxes that the user can check and delete that row in the table.  I have everything working, but if the user checks two boxes, it only retrieves the first one on the table.

```
<tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="id" value="${user.id}" /></td>
  <td><c:out value="${user.name}" /></td>
  <td><c:out value="${user.email}" /></td>
</tr>
```

This is just an example of my HTML.  Here is part of my servlet.

```
String id = request.getParameter("id");
```

So, again, I can get the first value selected, but I am not able to delete multiple rows on the same table.  Is there a function I can use or anything similar?
Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `getParameter()` indeed returns only the first one when there are multiple values on the same name. You need to use [`getParameterValues()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterValues-java.lang.String-) instead to get all of those values.

```
String[] ids = request.getParameterValues("id");
// ...
```

#### See also:

- [Send an Array with an HTTP Get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061273/send-an-array-with-an-http-get/)
- [ServletRequest.getParameterMap() returns Map<String, String[]> and ServletRequest.getParameter() returns String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928675/servletrequest-getparametermap-returns-mapstring-string-and-servletreques/)