# HTML/JSP How do i capture checkbox options and Store selected choices into Mysql Dbase. myChoice needs storing in db table under one column of a row

Tags: mysql, database, jsp, checkbox, store

Using HTML and JSP How do i capture checkbox options and Store selected choice into Mysql database. In the example below myChoice would have multiple answer and I want store in db table under one column of one row. (i know i could concatenate the choices) and store in one column but i am finding it hard to accomplish. 
Precisely i am struggling with capturing checkbox selection from HTML, concatenating choices into one string and storing in table. Any suggestions pls.

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@page import="java.util.Date" %>
<% Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); %>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title> My Mood Form</title>
</head>


<body>

    <%!
    public class Actor {
    String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test";
    String USERNAME = "XXXXX";
    String PASSWORD = "XXXXX";        

    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement insertActors = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;

        public Actor () {
            try {

           connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);

            insertActors = connection.prepareStatement(
                "INSERT INTO mood(first_name, last_name, my_choice, last_update)"
                + " VALUES (?,?,?,?)");

            } catch (SQLException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public int setActors (String first, String last, String choice, Timestamp  timeStamp){
            int result =0;
            try {
            insertActors.setString(1, first);
            insertActors.setString(2, last);   
            insertActors.setString(3, choice); 
            insertActors.setTimestamp(4, timeStamp); 
            result = insertActors.executeUpdate();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
        return result;
        }
    }
    %>


    <%
        int result = 0;
        if (request.getParameter("submit") != null){
            String firstName = new String ();
            String lastName = new String ();
            String myChoice = new String ();
            //String [] myChoice;

                if (request.getParameter("first") != null){
                    firstName = request.getParameter("first");
                }

                if (request.getParameter("last") != null){
                    lastName = request.getParameter("last");
                }

                if (request.getParameter("choice") != null){
                    myChoice = request.getParameter("choice");


                    /** 
                     * for (int i=0; i<selectedInterest.length; i++)
                            {
                               out.println(" " + selectedInterest[i] + "");
                               s = s +  selectedInterest[i] + ", "; 
                               out.println("s = " + s );
                            }
                    }
                    else{
                        out.println("none");

                    */

                }

            Date date = new Date();
            Timestamp timeStamp = new Timestamp (date.getTime());

            Actor mood = new Actor();
            result = mood.setActors(firstName, lastName, myChoice, timeStamp);
        }
    %>

    <h1>Registration Form</h1>
    <form name="Registration" action="index.jsp" method="POST">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="3">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Surname:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="first" size="40" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>First Name:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="last" size="40"  /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>My Choice:</td>
                    <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="excited" />I am excited<br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="happy" />I am happy <br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="indifference" />I am indifference<br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="sad" />I am sad<br>
                    </td>
                </tr>        

                <tr>
                    <td><button type="reset" value="Reset">Reset</button></td>
                    <td><button type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">Submit</button></td>                   </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing multiple request parameters with same name from table rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953212/passing-multiple-request-parameters-with-same-name-from-table-rows)