# How to get checked checkboxes in JSP

Tags: jsp, checkbox, jstl

How can I get/set checkbox value using jstl and delete only those record from the database where the checkbox is checked? can you also advise how to use ternary operators in jstl for this scenario?

SearchStudent.jsp

```
    <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn"%>

    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Lookup Students</title>
    </head>

    <form method="post" action="deleteStudentServlet" class="form">     
        <body class="body">

        <!-- List results -->

        <c:if test="${not empty studentList}">
            <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" :>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
                <c:forEach var="students" items="${studentList}">
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="chkBox"> </td>
                        <td>${students.studentID}</td>
                        <td>${students.title}</td>
                        <td>${students.firstName}</td>
                        <td>${students.lastName}</td>
                        <td><c:url value="UDS" var="url">
                                <c:param name="StudentID" value="${students.studentID}" />
                            </c:url> <a href="${url}">Edit</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>
            </table>
        </c:if>

        <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete" ></td>
    </form>

        <p>There are ${fn:length(studentList)} results.</p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your checkbox has currently no value associated with the parameter name at all:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chkBox">
```

So it's hard to find out the checked ones. You need to give the checkbox a value which uniquely identifies the selected item. In your particular example, the student ID seems to be an obvious choice:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="selected" value="${student.studentID}">
```

*(by the way, why are you duplicating the entity name in the property name? why not just name it `id` so that you can just self-documentary use `${student.id}`? also your `var="students"` is kind of odd, it is referring only **one** student, so just name it `var="student"`; the `${studentList}` can better be named `${students}`)*

When the form is submitted, all checked value are available as follows:

```
String[] selectedStudentIds = request.getParameterValues("selected");
```

Finally, just pass it through to your DAO/service class which does the business job:

```
studentService.delete(selectedStudentIds);
```

#### See also:

- [How to transfer data from JSP to servlet when submitting HTML form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4971877/how-to-transfer-data-from-jsp-to-servlet-when-submitting-html-form)
- [ServletRequest.getParameterMap() returns Map<String, String[]> and ServletRequest.getParameter() returns String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928675/servletrequest-getparametermap-returns-mapstring-string-and-servletreques)
- [Send an Array with an HTTP Get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061273/send-an-array-with-an-http-get)

Comment: My other question is that how does it know to get only "checked" values using 
                                                           
String[] selectedStudentIds = request.getParameterValues("selected");

Comment: and what if I want to select "unchecked" values?

Comment: Are you familiar with basic HTTP and HTML? All HTML input fields send their values as HTTP request parameters. If you want to get unchecked values, just substract the checked values (the `selectedStudentIds`) from all available values (the `studentList`).

Comment: Yes, i am new and learnig from experts like you. With regards to your answer, does it mean that when the checkbox is not selected, the value in it is null?

Comment: please can you provide an example of the subtraction?

Comment: An unchecked checkbox is not been sent as request parameter. Thus it does not end up in `selectedStudentIds`. As to substraction, just loop over all available items, get its ID and check if it's in the `selectedStudentIds`. If not, then it was not selected.

Answer (score -1):

this may help you.

In ajax call:

```
var boolValue= $(this).closest(".tr").find('.checkboxClass').is(':checked');

$.post("/api/dosomething", {                                     
    someSettings : boolValue
})
```