# Spring MVC data to HTML5

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jsp

i have been trying to print Java Data in JSP and unable to do certain fields of HTML5 Tag,

```
1) datetime-local : Java Format - String - " 2018-06-26 13:30:13.0"
                    Html Format - datetime-local requires -> " 2018-06-26T 13:30:13.0"
```

So is there any parser, which i can use in java to convert it?

```
2) check box : Java Format - boolean - "true"

can i use the boolean data to mark it true in HTML 5 checkbox.
```

i am new to SpringMVC 3, is there any library to use in HTML to make it work?

Comment: 1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469507/how-can-i-change-the-date-format-in-java

Comment: 2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12396828/how-to-get-checked-checkboxes-in-jsp

Comment: for datetime, i tried your first link: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'T' -> error which i get.

Comment: What is that "T" in this format ?

Comment: Put your code please

Answer (score 0):

> for datetime, i tried your first link: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'T' -> error which i get.

Try to use following date patterns and it will parse correctly

```
final String OLD_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S";
final String NEW_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd'T' HH:mm:ss.S";
```