# How can i get the value from a checkbox in jsp?

Tags: java, html

I want to try to get the value from a checkbox using JSP but so far with not success

```
  <%!
    // Define global variables
    String state = "off";
%>

      <%!
    public void getState(String state) {
        if(state.equals("on")){
            %> <h1>ON</h1> <%!
        }
  }
  %>


        <!-- Toggle button -->
        <div class="togglebutton">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" onclick="<% getState(state); %>">
              <span class="toggle"></span>
                Toggle is off
          </label>
        </div>
```

The thing with this code is that it print the function without being called!
any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: replace the `onclick` with a Javascript function see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9887360/how-can-i-check-if-a-checkbox-is-checked

Comment: thanks for answer but the thing is that the file is merely java code, any other suggestion ?

Comment: JSP can contain HTML and Javascript.

Comment: Yes, but this is a school practice where i am not allowed to use javascript code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get checked checkboxes in JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12396828/how-to-get-checked-checkboxes-in-jsp)

Answer (score 0):

`<input TYPE=checkbox name=sports VALUE=Cricket>`
try this syntax 
I hope the code work without error

Answer (score 0):

I think because you put a print statement in the if statement, try to follow this style

```
 <body>
      <%!               
      public int add(int a,int b)           
              {                                     
        return a+b;
              } 
       %>

      <% 
      int k;                
          k=add(5,6);
      %>

      <%=                   
          k                     
      %>

    </body>
```