# Update related data Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have this method update to update a data (jurnal data) that belongs to another data (edisi data), below is the code :

```
public function update(Jurnal $jurnal, JurnalRequest $request) {
        $input = $request->all();
        if ($request->hasFile('file') && $request->file('file')->isValid()) {
            // Delete old file
            $this->hapusPDF($jurnal);

            // Upload new file
            $input['file'] = $this->uploadPDF($request);
        }
        $id = $request->id; //retrieve id edisi

        $jurnal = Edisi::findOrFail($id)->jurnal()->update($input);
        return redirect()->route('edisi', ['id' => $id]);
    }
```

The method above gave me this error : No query results for model [App\Edisi]. My question is how to make my update method working ? Thank you ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to update single `journal` and `$jurnal` has the `journal id` you want to update, your update statement will be like below:

```
$jurnal = Jurnal::findOrfail($jurnal->id)->update($input);
```

Comment: yes I want to update single jurnal data that belongs to an edisi. So the problem is I want to keep the edisi id as well :)

Comment: But, as the Jurnal has its own primary key and edisi-jurnal have 1 to many relationship. I think you won't need the edisi->id. right ?

Comment: Yes the jurnal has its own primary key, and yes  both table have 1 to many relationship. So you mean to tell me that I don't need the edisi id ? If so how would I save the jurnal data to specified edisi ?

Comment: can you try above code . I think it would be enough to update

Comment: It's working now, seems like the problem is I forgot to request the edisi id  to edit method .. Anyway, thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

You're using `findOrFail($id)` and it doesn't find any row with `id = $id`, so it throws an exception. You can do this instead:

```
$edisi = Edisi::find($id);
if (!is_null($edisi)) {
    $jurnal = $edisi->jurnal()->update($input);
} else {
    echo 'There is no edisi with ID = '.$id;
    die();
}
```

Comment: tried this and gave me this error : Call to a member function jurnal() on null

Comment: Done, gave me this error : NotFoundHttpException in Router.php line 1006: with strange url : http://1mark.dev/edisi/%5B%5D

Comment: This means code works and it executes normally until `return redirect()->route('edisi', ['id' => $id]);` which builds wrong URL. `%5B%5D` is `[]`. Read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14160843/remove-5b5d-from-url-when-submitting-form

Comment: As I said above, Eloquent can't find `edisi` with specified ID. You can use `die` to terminate script. I've updated code above.

Comment: It's working now, seems like the problem is I forgot to request the edisi id to edit method .. Anyway, thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not retrieving any id using

```
$request->id
```

You should use

```
$request->get('id') // And you must ensure that there is an input with 'id' name comming from client
```

You could use too `$input['id']`.
I hope it helps.

Comment: `$request->id` is completely valid . https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests#retrieving-input