# Get all hidden input fields in JSF dynamically

Tags: jsf-2

I have some hidden inputs that are generated dynamically using JQuery. For example :

```
<input type="hidden" name="name1" value="SomeValue1">
<input type="hidden" name="name2" value="SomeValue2">
```

The method

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("name1")
```

returns the value `SomeValue1` which is correct. But, at runtime I am not aware of the input names. How can I get all the hidden inputs without knowing their names ?

Thansk for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give them all the same name, so that you can use [`getRequestParameterValuesMap()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getRequestParameterValuesMap()) instead.

```
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="SomeValue1">
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="SomeValue2">
...
```

```java
String[] names = externalContext.getRequestParameterValuesMap().get("name");
```

The ordering is guaranteed to be the same as in HTML DOM.

Alternatively, based on the incremental integer suffix as you've in the HTML DOM, you could also just get the request parameter in a loop until `null` is returned.

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 1; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
    String name = requestParameterMap.get("name" + i);

    if (name != null) {
        names.add(name);
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: @BalusC just for my curiosity, I am not so familiar with HTML, but I don't understand why we can add inputs whith same ID while its not possible in JSF? and also you said `requestParameterMap.get("name" + i);`, when that `i` is generated ? thanks in advance

Comment: @Tarik: `id` != `name`. As to `i`, that's in OP's case done by jQuery.

Comment: @BalusC Oh! I think I was confused because in the generated HTML of my JSF pages the name is always (I guess) the same as the id, is that always true ?

Comment: @Tarik: Not for `UISelectMany` components (e.g. multi-select checkbox/menu). See also a.o. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928675/servletrequest-getparametermap-returns-mapstring-string-and-servletreques/ for a basic JSP/servlet based answer.