# Collect and save submitted values of multiple dynamic HTML inputs back in servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets, jstl

I am able to display an `ArrayList` of beans in a JSP form using JSTL by looping through the list and outputting the bean properties in a HTML input tag.

```
<c:forEach items="${listOfBeans}" var="bean">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" id="foo" value="${bean.foo}"/></td>  
    <td><input type="text" id="bar" value="${bean.bar}"/></td>                     
  </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

How do I code the JSP so that when the page submits then the updated values are in the appropriate item of the the `ArrayList`?

Answer (score 4):

Given this simplified model:

```
public class Item {
    private Long id;
    private String foo;
    private String bar;
    // ...
}
```

Here's how you can do it provided `${items}` is `List<Item>`:

```
<c:forEach items="${items}" var="item">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="${item.id}" />
            <input name="foo_${item.id}" value="${fn:escapeXml(item.foo)}" />
        </td>  
        <td>
            <input name="bar_${item.id}" value="${fn:escapeXml(item.bar)}" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

<sup>(note the importance of fn:escapeXml() as [XSS attack prevention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658922/xss-prevention-in-jsp-servlet-web-application))</sup>

So, basically, you need to set the item's unique identifier as a hidden input field in each row as shown in above snippet:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="${item.id}" />
```

And you should in turn use this `id` as suffix of `name` of all input fields in the same row such as:

```
<input name="foo_${item.id}" ... />
```

In the servlet, you can collect all values of `<input type="hidden" name="id" ...>` from all rows by `request.getParameterValues()`. Just loop over it and then grab the individual inputs by `id`.

```
for (String id : request.getParameterValues("id")) {
    String foo = request.getParameter("foo_" + id);
    String bar = request.getParameter("bar_" + id);
    // ...
}
```

You can also do this all without that `id` and grab all inputs by name as an array like so `name="foo"` and `request.getParameterValues("foo")`, but the ordering of request parameters is not under your control. HTML forms will send it in order, but the enduser can easily manipulate the order.

No need for JavaScript mess here.

#### See also:

- [Show JDBC ResultSet in HTML in JSP page using MVC and DAO pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003142/show-jdbc-resultset-in-html-in-jsp-page-using-mvc-and-dao-pattern)
- [ServletRequest.getParameterMap() returns Map<String, String[]> and ServletRequest.getParameter() returns String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928675/servletrequest-getparametermap-returns-mapstring-string-and-servletreques)
- [Send an Array with an HTTP Get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061273/send-an-array-with-an-http-get)