# Get each value of input of td elements in a servlet?

Tags: html, jsp, servlets

I am new to servlets and JSP.  I have a table in my JSP page and I want to get all the values by using a `for` loop and then `save`.  I am unable to loop through the data in a table by tag names in the servlet and  I only get the first `td` value of the table.  I don't know where I made a mistake.

Here is my code:

```
<table class="table table-hover" id="attendanceTableId">
    <%for(int i=0;i<=se.size()-1;i++) {%>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="textbox" name="studentName"  value="<%=se.get(i)%>" readonly></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="status" value="present" style="width:15px;height:15px;"/>Present</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="status" value="absent" style="width:15px;height:15px;">Absent</td>
        </tr>
    <%} %>
</table>
```

And servlet is:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String rowCount=request.getParameter("rowCountHidden");
    int rowCountNum=Integer.parseInt(rowCount);
    System.out.println("rocount is"+rowCountNum);

    for (int i=1;i<=rowCountNum;i++) {
        String date=request.getParameter("date");
        String StudentName=request.getParameter("studentName");
        String status=request.getParameter("status");

        System.out.println("rocount is"+StudentName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35614753

Comment: //I tried like below and i got expected output.for (int i = 0; i <= rowCountNum - 1; i++) {
   String status[] = new String[rowCountNum];
   status[i] = request.getParameter(Integer.toString(i));
   System.out.println("status is :" + i + "," + status[i]);  }