# To insert the value of a text box present near the checked check box value into database

Tags: mysql, jsp, servlets, jdbc

I need help in inserting the value of a text box which is present near the checked check box value into the database as a single row

Product name is a check box and Description is a text box which is present near to the check box in a same row. If a check box value is checked then its corresponding text box value need to be inserted into the database along with the checked check box value.

For me the checked check box value is getting inserted into the database but its corresponding text box value is not getting inserted, instead the 1st text box value is getting inserted into the DB

This is my code

**Productlist.jsp**

```
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
    <%@page import="web.Products"%>
    <%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <form name="sform" method="post" action="Save_Products"> 
      <table style="width:40%">
          <tr> <th> Brand Name</th>
              <th> Product Name</th>
              <th> Description</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
               <td><%
  List<Products> pdts = (List<Products>) request.getAttribute("productlist");
  if(pdts!=null){
    for(Products prod: pdts){
  out.println("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"brand_name\" value=\""  + prod.getBrandname() + "\">");
      out.println("<br/>"+prod.getBrandname());

        } %> 
       <td><%
  if(pdts!=null){
    for(Products prod: pdts){
       out.println("<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"prod\" checked=\"checked\" value=\""  + prod.getProductname() + "\">"  + prod.getProductname()+"<br>");
        } } %> </td>
       <td><%
       if(pdts!=null){
       for(Products prod: pdts){
        out.println("<input type=\"text\" name=\"desc\" style=\"width:50px; height:22px\" value=\""+prod.getDesc()+"\"/><br/>");
    } 
   }  
   } %> </td>  
   </tr>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td align="center">  <input type="submit" value="Save" name="save"/> </td></tr> 

      </table>
         </form>
    </html>
```

**Servlet Code**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;


public class Save_Products extends HttpServlet {
 static final String dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pdt";
     static final String dbUser = "root";
     static final String dbPass = "root";
    @Override
     public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
         response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");    
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            ResultSet rs=null;
            Connection connection = null;  
            try{
      HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    String[] brand_name =request.getParameterValues("brand_name");
String [] prod_list = request.getParameterValues("prod");
String [] desc_list = request.getParameterValues("desc");
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
connection = DriverManager.getConnection (dbURL,dbUser,dbPass);

String sql="insert into pdt_list(brand_name,product_name,desc)values(?,?,?)";
PreparedStatement prep = connection.prepareStatement(sql); 
int num_values = Math.min(prod_list.size(), desc_list.size());

int count_updated = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < num_values; i++){
    prep.setString(1, brand_name[i]);
    prep.setString(2, prod_list[i]);
    prep.setString(3,desc_list[i]);
    count_updated += prep.executeUpdate();
}
if(count_updated>0)
{    
   out.print("Products Saved Successfully...");
 RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("Save_Success.jsp");    
            rd.forward(request,response);    
}
else{
    RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("Save_Failure.jsp");    
            rd.forward(request,response);   
}

prep.close();
       }
     catch(Exception E){
//Any Exceptions will be caught here
System.out.println("The error is"+E.getMessage());

    }  

        finally {
            try {
                connection.close();
            } 
        catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("The error is"+ex.getMessage());
            }
                }

}

}
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/35614753

Comment: I need to implement the logic using scriptlets and not using JSTL implementation

Comment: Just follow same logic as explained in the answer. The server side language used absolutely doesn't matter. This all just boils down to basic HTTP and HTML.

Comment: Need more clarification.Please help me in using the same logic in my code.

Comment: Your code basically needs a full rewrite. The kickoff example is already given in the duplicate. Use that until you got a working sample and alter it to match your requirements.